# how to refer to text contents of a cell as separate values in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i am trying to write an IF function with whether a cell contains the contents of another cell as the condition, but even if it contains other text within what was the text of the other cell, eg; if cell A1 contains "bananas" and A2 contains **ban**gd**anas** which includes the values within A1

(this is my current function
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A8,A9)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EM",A9))),MAX(E8:F8)-MAX(E9:F9),MAX(E8:F8))

but i want it to hold true even if A9 has what was in A8 split or cut up and i do not know how to do that.)

Comment: Pls include Your attempt too. Question: what if the string to find is cut up in more than one place? Still valid?

Comment: @JvdV  yes even if cut up in more than one place. i have no attempts because i have no idea what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft365:

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B1,TEXTJOIN("*",0,,MID(A1,SEQUENCE(LEN(A1)),1),)),"Found","Not Found")
```

In Excel 2019 you may use (CSE-entered):

```
=IF(COUNTIF(B1,TEXTJOIN("*",0,,MID(A1,ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A1))),1),)),"Found","Not Found")
```

Comment: @glanard, I cannot reproduce your error nor do I understand what A9 has to do with it. Can you confirm you have Excel365 at least?

Comment: i copied the sheet in your picture exactly and i copied and pasted in the sheet from your answer, yet it says "not found" in both C1 and C2. why is this what am i doing wrong [you can see the formula i put in and the results over here](https://ibb.co/2yTRWDn)

Comment: (my excel is 2019 MSO (16.0.10370.20052) 64-bit)

Comment: @glanard, you may not have access to the `SEQUENCE()` funtion. Therefor I updated the answer to include an Excel 2019 version which needs be cse-entered.

Comment: thank you, but now it says "found" in both (whether it's true or false) [screenshot](https://ibb.co/55sdcJL)

Comment: @glanard. Have you used cse-confirmation?

Comment: got it. [it works.](https://ibb.co/59451LM) thank you !!

Comment: i need to use this with different versions of excel. is there a way to change the workbook based on which version of excel opened it ?